# jqform validation issue in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

using bootstrap for responsive purpose based on that also using jqbootstrapvalidation but not working middle of the table or td it's only working out of the div can any one help how to validate each fields in the table or td

Thanks in advance

```
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () { $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation(); } );
    </script>

<form>
<div class="row-fluid section">
        <div class="span12">
                    <table table table-condensed>

                            <tr>
                                <td><label><b>Form One</b></label></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="25%">Market:</td>
                                <td width="25%"><select><option>-------Select-----------</option><option>--one--</option><option>--two--</option></select></td>
                                <td width="25%">Birth Date(mmddyyyy):</td>
                                <td width="15%"><input type="text"></input></td>
                                <td><i class="icon-calendar" style="position:relative;right:30px;"></i></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="30%">PIN:</td>
                                <td width="30%"><input type="text"></input></td> 
                            </tr>
                    </table>
        </div>
    </div>

<br/>
<div class="row-fluid section">
        <div class="span12">
                    <table table table-condensed>

                            <tr>
                                <td><label> <b>Form Two</b></label></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="12%">First Name:</td>
                                <td width="12%"><input type="text"></input></td>
                                <td width="12%">Init:</td>
                                <td width="12%"><input type="text" class="inputw100"></input></td>
                                <td width="12%">Last Name:</td>
                                <td width="12%"><input type="text"></input></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="30%">Address1:</td>
                                <td width="30%"><input type="text" class="inputw190"></input></td> 
                                <td width="30%">Address2:</td>
                                <td width="30%"><input type="text" class="inputw190"></input></td> 
                            </tr>


                            <tr>
                                <td width="12%">City:</td>
                                <td width="12%"><input type="text"></input></td>
                                <td width="12%">State:</td>
                                <td width="12%"><input type="text"></input></td>
                                <td width="12%">Zip:</td>
                                <td width="12%"><input type="text" class="inputw100"></input></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="12%">Contact Number:</td>
                                <td width="12%"><input type="text"></input></td>
                                <td width="12%">Welcome E-mail Address:</td>
                                <td width="12%"><input type="text"></input></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="30%">Authorized User:</td>
                                <td width="30%"><input type="text"></input></td>
                            </tr>

                    </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You have not specified any HTML5 validation attributes for your inputs. E.g. add `required` if the field is mandatory. Documentation is here: http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/

Comment: can you able to show with my code because i tried in that way also.

Comment: fiddle link of my code http://jsfiddle.net/Ecr9v/2/

Comment: Works for me - added HTML5 validation attributes to birth date and last name fields: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/baUdJ/4/

Comment: thanks for your reply. But my issue is present working one field not working for other fields check it this http://jsfiddle.net/baUdJ/5/                             even i placed two Date validation also not working and given input as number & required not working please help on this. if you give the solution for entire form that will be helpful to understand.